# <Model>.findOne() in mongoose, not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This is my entire code. I have tried a lot of things still not working out. post request on postman shows a load and then crashes. there is no error message

```
    const express = require('express');
    const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');
    const app = express();

    app.use(express.json());

    // // Connection URL
    var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
    var db = "mongodb://localhost:27017/userDb";
    MongoClient.connect(db, { useNewUrlParser: true }, function (err, db) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("Mongo DB Connected...!");
        //   db.close();
    });
```

// User Database

```
    const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
    const UserSchema = new Schema({
        username: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            minlength: 5,
            maxlength: 50
        },
        password: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            minlength: 5,
            maxlength: 1024
        },
        hash: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            minlength: 5,
            maxlength: 1024
        },
    });
    var User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

//Register New User

```
    app.post('/register', async (req, res) => {
        console.log('try registering : ', req.body);
        console.log(User);
```

// Check if this user already exisits

```
        console.log('in here');
```

//this is where its not working

```
        let user = await User.findOne({ username: req.body.username });
        if (user) {
            return res.status(400).send('That user already exisits!');
        }
        // Encrypt Password
        try {
            console.log('Encrypt');
            bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
                bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, salt, (err, hash) => {
                    console.log('-----password:', hash, '& salt', salt, '-----');
                    passwordHash = hash;
                    saltHash = salt;
                    user = new User({
                        username: req.body.username,
                        password: passwordHash,
                        hash: saltHash,
                    });
                    console.log(user);
                    user.save();
                    res.send('Registered');
                });
            });
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
```

Login User

```
    app.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
        console.log('try Login : ', req.body);
        let user = await User.findOne({ username: req.body.username });
        // console.log(user);
        if (!user) {
            return res.status(400).send('Incorrect username');
        }
        console.log(user);
        console.log('decrypting entered password');
```

Decrypt Password

```
        const passwordHash = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, user.hash);
        if (passwordHash == user.password) {
            // console.log("in")
            res.send('You are logged in!');
        } else {
            console.log('incorrect password');
        }

    });
```

I am creating my port here

```
    //PORT
    const port = process.env.PORT || 3020;
    app.listen(port, () => console.log(`listening on port ${port}...`));
```

Comment: What's the error message coming up? @Saloni

Comment: @PrasantaBose it's loading on postman and crashing. no error message. the part where i use findOne() isn't working. if i comment out that line of code `let user = await User.findOne({ username: req.body.username });` then the program runs

Comment: Can you push this to git? I can have a look then. @Saloni

Comment: @PrasantaBose there you go [Git link](https://github.com/SalonSikdar/Login-API)

Comment: Check mine reply below. @Saloni

Comment: @PrasantaBose thanks a lot for the fix :) ; and the advice is much needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I have fixed your code.
See here. [link](https://github.com/boseprasanta/Login-API/blob/master/loginAPI.js)

There is something I'll like to point out.

1. Use either mongoose or MongoClient. Try learning mongoose it's easier to code with mongoose.
2. Always put your DB references or query executions inside try-catch.
3. Return doesn't serve it's purpose inside try. Throw an error there.

That's all. Try to learn a better code structure. If there's some doubt let me know.

Comment: Please do upvote and accept my answer. If it helped. @SaloniSikdar

Comment: i did! but i have too less reps for my vote to count. :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the User.findOne to below-mentioned code:

```
let user = await User.findOne({ username: req.body.username }).exec();
```

Change this and let us know the outcome.